# Angular 2 Routing exception

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Worked on my project 3d ago. after that just pushed it into my repo. 
Today i cloned repo and install dependencies. 
If early it worked good today i have bunch of errors.

When i trying to get sell `<a routerLink="/sell">Sell</a>` page by url -> localhost:3000/sell

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{
  path: '',
  component: MainPageComponent
},
{
  path: 'sell',
  component: SellComponent  }
];
```

I'm getting this error 
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iUSn.png)

Note: It worked till this day.
Thanks for help

Comment: I don't think the error is in the code. You should add `, pathMatch: 'full'` to the first (empty path) route though if it is not a redirect and doesn't have child routes.

Comment: wow it solve my problem 
leave answer i'll mark

Comment: Didn't really expect that either :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `, pathMatch: 'full'` to the first (empty path) route though if it is not a redirect and doesn't have child routes.